# Combining multiple MarkLogic queries with cts:search

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, cts-search

I am trying to query a database of documents in MarkLogic to find any that fit several parameters:

This MUST be true

1. A list of authors must contain an author ID provided

And EITHER of these must be true:

2. A list of `extra-documents` must have a `date-added` field on any of them that is more recent than the provided date
3. The document itself must have a `newer-document-date` field that is more recent than the provided date

For example, someone may pass in an `authorId` of `10`, and a `dateTime` of `2017-01-01T00:00:00`

Below are samples explaining why they should/shouldn't be returned (removed extraneous XML)

```
This document should be returned because it has an extra-document with a date-added that is more recent than the provided date, and a matching author.
<metadata>
<extra-documents>
   <extra-document>
      <date-added>2018-09-11T00:00:00</date-added>
   </extra-document>
</extra-documents>
<book-authors>
   <book-author>10</book-author>
   <book-author>20</book-author>
</book-family-authors>
</metadata>

This document should be returned because it has a newer-document-date greater than the provided date
<metadata>
<extra-documents>
   <extra-document>
      <date-added>2000-09-11T00:00:00</date-added>
   </extra-document>
</extra-documents>
<book-authors>
   <book-author>10</book-author>
   <book-author>20</book-author>
</book-family-authors>
<newer-document-date>2019-02-03T00:00:00</newer-document-date>
</metadata>


This document should NOT be returned because it is missing the author, even though it fills the date requirement on both the extra-document and the newer-document-date
<metadata>
<extra-documents>
   <extra-document>
      <date-added>2020-09-05T00:00:00</date-added>
   </extra-document>
</extra-documents>
<book-authors>
   <book-author>20</book-author>
</book-family-authors>
<newer-document-date>2019-02-03T00:00:00</newer-document-date>
</metadata>
```

I am new to using `cts:search`, and am having trouble figuring out how to build a complex query like this that can search specific nodes. The best I have come up with is this:

```
cts:search(/*, 
        cts:and-query (( 
            cts:search(/*:metadata/*:book-authors/*:book-author, $author-id),
            cts:element-query(
                    fn:QName("http://example.com/collection/book-metadata", "newer-document-date"), 
                    cts:true-query()
            ), <-- this element-query was an attempt to make sure the field exists on the book, as some books don't have this field
            cts:search(/*:metadata,
                cts:element-range-query(fn:QName("http://example.com/collection/book-metadata", "newer-document-date"), "<", $date-from)
            ))
        )
    )
```

However, this doesn't seem to work correctly, and trying to add the 3rd requirement has been extremely difficult, to the point that I am simply trying to get these first 2 implemented right now. Any help on this is appreciated. I'm unsure if `cts:search` is the best approach for this, or if I am using things like `/*:metadata...` correctly for searching specific fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the two queries looking for either the existence of the `date-added` element or the `newer-document-date` with a value less than the `$date-from` inside of a [`cts:or-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:or-query), and apply that inside of a [`cts:and-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-query) along with the `cts:element-value-query()` for the `$author-id` values:

```
declare namespace meta = "http://example.com/collection/book-metadata";
cts:search(doc(),
  cts:and-query((
    cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("meta:book-author"), $author-id),
    cts:or-query((
      cts:element-query(xs:QName("meta:date-added"), cts:true-query()),
      cts:element-range-query(xs:QName("meta:newer-document-date"), "<", "$date-from")
    ))
  ))
)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the jumpstart I needed to get it working properly. Figuring out how to order the results based on the date now.

Comment: Apply the order option (third parameter to cts:search) and specify the range index for the date element https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:index-order

Comment: Yep, found that documentation and was able to get it ordered quickly! cts:search is making much more sense to me now after getting over the initial hurdle.